# Linkedin Unsupported POST target

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have virtual host in my computer, project for symfony http://aog.local/app_dev.php and I create path http://aog.local/app_dev.php/auth/linkedin for linkedin connection but today its not work, I start dump($response->getResponse()) and I have:

```
    LinkedinProvider.php on line 24:
    array:5 [
    "errorCode" => 0
    "message" => "Unsupported POST target {/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-
name,email-address,picture-url)}"
    "requestId" => "2O8YQUBKIV"
    "status" => 405
    "timestamp" => 1434004701130
]
```

but yesterday all work ok. And I have another URL http://bb.test/app_dev.php/ this is virtual host in my computer too, to connection http://bb.test/app_dev.php/auth/linkedin in this project all work fine this

```
    LinkedinProvider.php on line 24:
    array:4 [
    "emailAddress" => "shuba.ivan.vikt@gmail.com"
    "formattedName" => "Ivan Shuba"
    "id" => "C_vOx_qVcv"
    "pictureUrl" => "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_OCZwJKsgekwl-EEy-
 125jtryenwltHzrUNawpkjy2tyrcZqgRQa5BFrgoiQuNd6j-
C2L-C0j3tuKAu4ABAgBAktAktuAAuKjBAgeV5bp7PMgRswTR8I6sAWDXFn3ZuF2OtJbgBD5pKW"
]
```

And I not understand what is change. This is projekts have identical code for linkedin connection and work for one apps and have identic credentials   and yesterday all work. Help please

Comment: I solved my problem, come back bundle:
`"hwi/oauth-bundle": "dev-master#a9f88f394e4680d5383b9a129f0e21fc74ca187f",
`

Comment: sorry, what was your solution?

Comment: use api facebook version 2.3